# SpringBoot Datasource AutoConfiguration Not Working

Tags: spring-boot, datasource

I have a simple SpringBoot application and I'd like to use AutoConfiguration to configure the Tomcat jdbc pooled data sources.

I am using these Spring dependencies:

```
// Spring Boot
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.3.5.RELEASE'
```

Here are my datasource properties in my application.yml file:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://my.host/mydb
        username: user
        password: pwd
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        initialSize: 5
```

I am sure the properties are being loaded because the app is picking up other values.

I define the bean in my config file as:

```
@Bean(name="myDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    return dataSource
}
```

And I inject the datasource into my DAO like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
class MyDAO {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource

    public void getFoo() {
        log.info("DB URL: ${dataSource.getUrl()}")
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the getDataSource() method, the DataSourceBuilder will create an instance of DataSource. However, all the properties of that object like URL, user and password are all null. Also, when I call getFoo(), the dataSource variable is null. I have tried commenting out the bean definition in my AppConfig. The dataSource is still null. Any suggestions?

I looked through the Spring Boot documentation and my Spring book but I didn't see any examples like this. I see examples where I create the DataSource myself. But I was hoping Spring's auto-configuration would tie this stuff together automatically.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

By creating your own bean, you're actually switching off Boot's auto-configuration of a `DataSource`. You can just delete your `getDataSource` method and let Boot auto-configure one instead.

Comment: I've updated the question to include how I'm injecting the bean. I tried commenting out the creation of the bean in my Java config. Doing that, the injected DataSource is null.

Comment: Something that's injected by Spring shouldn't be null.  How are you getting the instance of MyDAO with a null data source?

Comment: You were spot on. I was new-ing the DAO object. Once I changed that and added the SpringBoot JPA dependency, it works. I am trying to get enough points to mark your answer useful. Once I get up there, I'll give you a tick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Andy's comments I found out that I had two problems. First of all, I needed to include the JPA dependency to the project. I added this line to my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.5.RELEASE'
```

Second, I was creating instances of MyDAO using new(). I fixed this by creating a service class that used @Autowired to inject an instance of MyDAO. Once the DAO became a Spring managed bean, it was able to inject the instance of DataSource from the Tomcat connection pool.